# Highlight patterns in command output (grep-like but without excluding lines)

Tags: command-line, terminal, search, highlighting

I need a command that colorizes some symbol sequence in output of a certain command. I'd like it like `grep` make it.

```
$ some-command | grep symbol-sequence
```

However `grep` removed lines that isn't contained `symbol-sequence`. I'd like to have all original lines with highlighted `symbol-sequence`. How it can be done?

---

I have `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: add an `--color=always` at the end of the line

Comment: @val0x00ff Good point, but this doesn't solve the OP's problem who would like to have also the lines that don't match in the output.

Comment: @val0x00ff - Thank you. However, I have colorized output always. I expanded question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [ANSI control characters](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm):

```
some-command | sed 's/symbol-sequence/^[[0;32;2m symbol-sequence^[[0;0m/'
```

The characters `^[` are not a regular `^` followed by a regular `[`. It is an unprintable character. You can get it on most terminal by typing `Ctrl-v Ctrl-Esc`. The second `[` is a real `[` though.

If you prefer full-ascii, here is a copy-pastable version which has the same effect:

```
some-command | sed 's/symbol-sequence/\x1B[0;32;2m symbol-sequence\x1B[0;0m/'
```

You can change the "32" and the "2" in the above command to change the colors and style in the output. Look for "ANSI escape sequences" in any search engine for details and color codes.